# How to query a database after render_template

Tags: python, sqlite, flask

I have two SQLite tables. Both share the same "ID" primary key. Through flask I have sent all the information(Table 1) I wanted to display to html in a table format. I wanted to query the "id" of (Table 1) and get the results from (Table 2) when clicked on a row.

I have looked at sql.js (Javascript), but I do know that is not web secure.
I know looping through another list of dicts from cur.fetchall() is not a solution either.

Simplest solution is to somehow send back the "id" back to the python script and query from there. Don't know how to do that without form. I have looked into AJAX, but does not make much sense to me.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Read more about AJAX. This has very little to do with Python.

Comment: How do I relate ajax to flask?

Answer (score 2):

The "easy" way (no ajax) is to have a link next to each entry from table 1 that points to a new page that contains the related information from table 2. Example:

```
@app.route('/table1')
def show_table1():
    data = Table1.query.all()
    return render_template('table1.html', data = data)

@app.route('/table2/<int:id>')
def show_table2(id):
    item = Table2.query.get(id)
    return render_template('table2.html', table2_item = item)
```

The table 1 template would show the list of elements, and for each it will show a link to the related table 2 page:

```
{% for item in data %}
    {{ item.name }} <a href="{{ url_for('show_table2', id = item.id) }}">Click for more information</a>
{% endfor %}
```

And then `table2.html` would just show the data and offer a link back to the table 1 page:

```
{{ table2_item.name }}
<a href="{{ url_for('show_table1') }}">Go back</a>
```

A more sophisticated approach would do all this in the same page using ajax, but for that you'll need to write some Javascript to insert the data dynamically into the HTML document.

I hope this helps.